# POSIX Semaphores parent semaphore value is unaffected

Tags: c, linux, posix, ipc, semaphore

I am learning POSIX Semaphores.

Wrote a basic code which allows share POSIX Semaphores between parent and child. Why is the semaphore value not changed in parent after child updates it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_sem_value(sem_t *sem)
{
    int sem_value;

    if (sem_getvalue(sem, &sem_value) != 0) {
        perror("sem_getvalue");
    } else {
        printf("%d:Semaphore value:%d\n", getpid(), sem_value);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    sem_t sem;

    sem_init(&sem, 1, 3);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        print_sem_value(&sem);
        sem_wait(&sem);
        print_sem_value(&sem);
        sem_wait(&sem);
        print_sem_value(&sem);
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        wait(NULL);
        print_sem_value(&sem);
        sem_post(&sem);
        print_sem_value(&sem);
    }
    sem_destroy(&sem);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the semaphore value not changed in parent after child updates it.

You create an unnamed, process-shared semaphore, which is appropriate for your purpose, but you have not caused it actually to be shared.  As [the `sem_init` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html) documents:

> If `pshared` is nonzero, then the semaphore is shared between
>          processes, and should be located in a region of shared memory (see
>          `shm_open(`**3**`)`, `mmap(`**2**`)`, and `shmget(`**2**`)`).

If you don't adhere to that then the child gets its own copy of the semaphore, which does not interact with the parent's, process-shared status notwithstanding.

Once you fix that, do note also that only one process should `sem_destroy()` the semaphore, whereas in your current code, both processes (attempt to) do.